# Django - After creating index.fcgi and .htaccess it still displays the "Index Of/" page instead of Congratulations

Tags: django, fastcgi

Currently I've set up my fcgi and .htaccess as so

index.fcgi

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
import sys, os, user

#Add a custom Python path. (optional)
sys.path.insert(0, "/home3/username/www/newproject")

# Switch to the directory of your project.
os.chdir("/home3/username/www/newproject")

# Set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable.
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "newproject.settings"

from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")
```

---

.htaccess

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule (media/.*)$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(admin/.*)$ index.fcgi/$1 [L]
```

additional information:
the path of where I created my django project is /home3/username/www/
and 
"which python" returns /usr/local/bin/python

Currently, I have not touched the newproject folder except for creating a new app. I am trying to get to the "Congratulations, it worked!" page.

As a note, I did in fact change "username" to my proper username I just changed it back for privacy reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your .htaccess to:

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (media/.*)$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```